# What is the authoritative list of Docker Run exit codes?

Tags: docker, exitstatus

Apologies if this has been asked, but nowhere in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/) can I find an authoritative list of exit codes (also called exit status). Surprising! I see suggestions about making it consistent, but no docs on docker.com.

Does anyone know where the exit codes can be found?

Comment: in the source code ?

Comment: I'm very sorry if I was unclear. What about errors? For example if I `docker run -v non_existent_directory` or perhaps `docker run improper_container_path`  There is a lot that can go wrong, and the exit code should reflect this.

Answer (score 115):

For Docker >= 1.10 see [this PR](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14012), which follows standard [chroot exit codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html):

- `125`: `docker run` itself fails
- `126`: contained command cannot be invoked
- `127`: if contained command cannot be found
- `128 + n` Fatal error signal `n`:

  - `130` = `(128+2)` Container terminated by Control-C
  - `137` = `(128+9)` Container received a `SIGKILL`
  - `143` = `(128+15)` Container received a `SIGTERM`

Check the man page of `signal` for the full list (on cmd type `man 7 signal` or check online e.g. [signal](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Check [Docker's exit status documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status) for more information about the current version.

Comment: And with that PR the docs were also updated: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/exit-status

Comment: “128 + n” — I don’t see any evidence in either the referenced PR or docs that there is any such handling.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall That's pretty standard. E.g., in `man bash`: "The return value of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+n if the command is terminated by signal n".

Answer (score 19):

Normally it will be the exit status of the process, so it's application dependent i.e:

```
$ docker run debian sh -c "exit 5;"
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7fcc37778df0        debian              "sh -c 'exit 5;'"   4 seconds ago       Exited (5) 3 seconds ago                       reverent_einstein
```

But in certain cases Docker itself can return an exit code:

- 125 if the Docker daemon has an error (e.g. a wrong flag is provided)
- 126 if the container command can't be invoked (e.g. file isn't executable)
- 127 if the container command can't be found (e.g. wrong path to binary)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status