# Docker exiting with status code 139

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a .Net Core application what it to run on a docker image. I typed in the command line :

```
docker run -d --net=bridge -it --name=testapp -v /var/test/:/var/test microsoft/aspnetcore-build /bin/bash -c "dotnet /var/test/test.dll"
```

it is created but it is exiting with a status code 139. What could be the problem.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35410993/21567): `139` is essentially the running program inside the container failing with Signal 11, which is a segmentation fault `SIGSEGV`. Test your code outside the container, or run it inside with a debugger attached. There are multiple ways to do the later (google ".net core debug inside container" for a list of options).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running the docker image and running the bash command (-c "dotnet /var/test/test.dll") at the same time, divide it to steps.

For example:

1. run this command:

   ```
   docker run -d --net=bridge -it --name=testapp -v /var/test/:/var/test microsoft/aspnetcore-build
   ```

   it will run an aspnetcore Image named testapp and map the test file between the your machine and the docker machine.
2. enter the docker machine:

   ```
    docker exec -it testapp bash
   ```
3. enter the /var/test folder and run the app:

   ```
    dotnet test.dll
   ```

Comment: The run won't work either if the container process crashes right off.

Answer (score -3):

I fixed Docker error 139 in my project by adding a COPY line before my RUN line in Dockerfile:

```
COPY blueprint/src/main/python/setup.py setup.py
RUN python setup.py
```