# Mysql container exits with status: Exited (139)

Tags: mysql, docker

I am facing an issue when i want to run a mysql container: I tried with the example command i found on the Docker hub:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.6.24
```

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
2569c1a8cbd2        mysql:5.6.24        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   5 seconds ago       Exited (139) 4 seconds ago                       some-mysql
```

Shows that the container exited with code 139

And i can't have a single line of logs: the return of the docker logs command is empty...

```
~ docker logs 2569c1a8cbd2 
~
```

I am using Docker(v19.03.1, build 74b1e89) for Debian(v10.0)

Comment: strange. I ran the same command on my machine and it works. Have you tried with latest version of mysql? What OS are you using? What is your docker version?

Comment: Yes i tried with the latest version of mysql and it is working correctly, but i need this version in order to match with the mysql used in production...
Im using docker v19.03.1 on debian(v10.0)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724237/docker-exiting-with-status-code-139?rq=1

Comment: one thing to check , make sure you are using  x86/amd64 architecture since  that only  this image supports

Comment: Hi, yes i checked, I am using a x86/amd64 architecture...

Answer (score 1):

Are you running other containers? (maybe a separate project?)

I have two separate projects with their separate docker-compose files and their own services.

When one is running, the one with a mysql/mariadb container exits with 139. If I `docker-compose down` the other project, then the mysql container starts correctly.

I'm still figuring out *why* (came here for an answer to my problem), but you might have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue after an upgrade from Debian 9 to 11. The `mysql:5.6.24` Docker image just doesn't want to start. My solution was to upgrade to image `mysql:5-debian`

https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/5-debian/images/sha256-5adbbb05d43e67a7ed5f4856d3831b22ece5178d23c565b31cef61f92e3467ea?context=explore

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Macbook Pro M1.

In Docker Desktop

`Settings -> Features in development`

Untick "**Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon**"

[image]

Source: https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384#issuecomment-1519853919